# Changing default value for null string to datetime conversion in sql server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a web from that has a few text boxes which are visible only under certain conditions.  These textboxes are bound to calender extenders.However whenever not visible these pass null string to the database. Their corresponding datatype in the table is `datetime`. While storing these null strings they are converted to `1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM`. How can i have a null value stored here instead ?

Do i need to change the data type to some thing else ??

I'm using `datetime` because i need to perform some comparison operations later.

Relevant code is here.

```
public class Asset
{ 

public string dbStatus { get; set; }
public string wtyEndDate { get; set; }
public string amcEndDate { get; set; }


 public Asset()
 {
    dbStatus = default(String);
    wtyEndDate = default(String);
    amcEndDate = default(String);
 }
}

 protected void btnSaveAsset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { 
    Asset a = new Asset();
    a.wtyEndDate = txtWtyEndDate.Text;
    a.amcEndDate = txtAmcEndDate.Text;
    string msg = "";
    if (a.dbStatus == "INSERT")
    {
      try
       {
           msg = (ab.EXE_Assets_Master(a).Rows.Count>0) ? "Record Inserted"; : "Error"
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            msg = "Record with this service tag already exists in the database";
        }
    }
 }

 protected DataTable _EXE_Asset_Details(Asset a)
  {
    Parameters.Clear();

    AddParameter("@wtyEndDate", a.wtyEndDate);
    AddParameter("@amcEndDate",a.amcEndDate);
    AddParameter("@DBStatus", a.dbStatus);

    return ExecuteDataSet("[Asset_Details]").Tables[0];
    }

// Asset_Details

CREATE PROCEDURE [Asset_Details]
@wtyEndDate datetime = NULL, 
@amcEndDate datetime =null, 
@dbStatus nvarchar(50)

AS
IF(@DBStatus='INSERT')
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO [assetsMaster]
       ([warrantyEndDate],[amcEndDate])
  VALUES
       ( @wtyEndDate,@amcEndDate)
  SELECT @@rowcount

END
```

Comment: Do you have a default defined on the column? How are you inserting to the database? If you are passing in `DateTime` objects, these are value types with the default value that you have posted.

Comment: I'm assigning strings to the parameters of a stored procedure. The corresponding parameters have `datetime` datatype.

Comment: Please post your code. As I said, there is no such thing as a `null` `DateTime` - you need to pass in a `null` as the parameter value if you want it to be `null` in the database.

Comment: I asked that you post the relevant code. I am asking again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only add the optional `DateTime` parameters if they have data in them.

For example:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a.wtyEndDate))
{
    AddParameter("@wtyEndDate", a.wtyEndDate);
}
```

Comment: and also change the data types in Asset class to `DateTime` instead of `string` ??

Comment: @Parminder - That would certainly be a good idea, for other reasons. It would **not** help with the issue you are having. As I commented before - `DateTime` objects are _value types_ and **can't** be `null`.